# How to install an angular plugin via a zip file?

Tags: angular, tinymce

I have my own self-hosting version of TinyMCE in a zip file that I wish to install to my angular app but I do not know how. All I could find are posts about people doing this without internet but this seems overly complicated for my use case.

I have tried adding it to node_modules and adding a scirpt src to it in index.html but with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE cannot be run as a zip file - the individual files need to be available to the browser to be loaded from the server at runtime.

Is you are using Angular I am going to assume you use NPM so one option is to include TinyMCE via NPM.

You can certainly pull down the files as a zip and place them somewhere in your project as well.  In the end all NPM is doing is providing a different way to download the files for TinyMCE.

Once you have the files they need to be somewhere that the browser using your application can reference them at runtime.  As you can do lots of different things with your application structure it is hard to say exactly where you can place TinyMCE. I usually have a `scripts` folder in my Vue projects (I don't use Angular any longer) and I make sure any JavaScript needed at runtime is deployed to the `scripts` folder.  Assuming you were to place all of the TinyMCE runtime files in a `scripts` folder you just use a `<script>` tag in the head of your page to load TinyMCE.

There are certainly other options...

1. **Module Loaders** - you can choose to load TinyMCE only in the components that need to have TinyMCE.  We have documentation on that here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/
2. **TinyMCE Angular "wrapper"** - we have a wrapper that makes it easier to get TinyMCE running in Angular: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular2/.  This wrapper further simplifies getting TinyMCE working in Angular.  The wrapper will (by default) load TinyMCE from our Cloud platform if TinyMCE is not already available locally.  This may be the least work for you but would require registering for a ***free*** API key for our Cloud platform (free!).